# Find $Q''\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)$ where $Q(x) = 5-3(x-2)+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{(x-2)^n}{n(n-1)}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation, taylor-expansion

Find $Q''\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)$ where $Q(x) = 5-3(x-2)+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{(x-2)^n}{n(n-1)}$. I think I am supposed to use Taylor series, but in what way?

Comment: Perform the sum then take two derivatives to find:  $\frac{1}{3-x}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**
$${d^2\over dx^2}{(x-2)^n\over n(n-1)}=(x-2)^{n-2}\quad,\quad n>1$$

Comment: How do I deal with the first part of the function?

Comment: It is simply zero since $${d^2\over dx^2}ax+b=0$$

Comment: In that case I would think the answer would be 2 as that is the value of (x-2)^n-2 where x = 3/2 and n is increasing from 2, but this is not correct.

Comment: No. You should first sum up $(x-2)^{n-2}$ from $n=2$ to $\infty$ and then plug $3\over 2$ in the result.

Comment: This would appear to be (x-2)^0 + (x-2)^1 + (x-2)^2 + ...... (x-2)^inf, but this would give the same answer.

Comment: Never mind, I got it! Thanks

Comment: The answer becomes $2\over 3$. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Note that taking the second derivative of $Q(x)$ causes constant and linear terms to disappear thus: \begin{align*}
 Q''(x) &= \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \dfrac{n(n-1)\cdot (x-2)^{n-2}}{n(n-1)} \\
  &= \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} (x-2)^{n-2}.
\end{align*}Therefore $Q''$ is given by a geometric series, so
$$Q''\left(\dfrac{3}{2}\right)=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \left(-\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^{n-2} = \dfrac{1}{1-\left(-\dfrac{1}{2}\right)} = \dfrac{1}{~3/2~} = \boxed{\dfrac{2}{3}}.$$

Answer (score -1):

$$Q(x) = 5-3(x-2)+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{(x-2)^n}{n(n-1)}$$
Differentiate
$$Q'(x) = -3+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{(x-2)^{n-1}}{(n-1)}$$
Differentiate again:
$$Q''(x) = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}{(x-2)^{n-2}}$$
Change the index of summation:
$$Q''(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{(x-2)^{n}}$$
$$Q''\left(\frac 3 2 \right) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\left(-\dfrac 12 \right)^{n}}$$
Apply the Taylor formula for $|x|<1$ :
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{n}=\dfrac 1 {1-x}$$